# Excel VBA Code for changing the value if found duplicates in the specific Column

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I am a beginner in Excel VBA. I just wanna know what code I am going to used for changing the value of the selected row/column if found duplicate. Example in the picture I attached, `B804 & B805` have the same value. In `Column C`, I used the formula of adding a number if found if it is duplicated. What I want to do in VBA code is, I want to delete the formula (without affecting the other cell) in `Column C` or `C805` but it will ask a question first like "Work order was already mentioned, would you like to proceed?" then if the user will click "yes" then the procedure is to delete the formula in `C805` and find the duplicate value in column b and paste the same value (means whatever the result in formula in the column c will the same result also will be pasted if found if it is duplicated).

I tried a code but I don't have any idea what to put next. I hope you can help me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B2399")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 2)
            '.Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
    If Range("C1").Value = "Formula" Then
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("C:C").Value = .Duplicate Then
        UserForm4.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set RNG = Range("B2:B2399")
    
    If Intersect(Target(1), RNG) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Target(1).Value
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(RNG, v) > 1 Then 'find duplicates
        If MsgBox("Work order was already mentioned, would you like to proceed?", _
            vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Duplicate found") = vbYes Then
            
            Row = Application.Match(v, Columns("B"), 0) 'find the row with the duplicate
            If IsNumeric(Row) Then
                Target(1).Offset(, 1) = Cells(Row, 3)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```